# How to change btrfs partition label/uuid?

Tags: dual-boot, btrfs

I upgraded to a new harddisk by using dd to copy the partition. As the old disk is still in place, the computer seems to randomly boot one or another.
To fix this I thought, changing the UUID/LABEL of the disk and adjusting /etc/fstab accordingly might help.

However I don't find a command with similar capabilities as tune2fs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

David Sterba has recently committed an UUID change option for `btrfstune`. You use it as `btrfstune -U <uuid> <device>`.

Answer (score 1):

Appears changing UUID is not possible on btrfs!?!!

[check this](http://blog.the-jedi.co.uk/tag/btrfs/)